# Can a F-35 shoot while hovering?

Tags: aircraft-design, fighter, thrust-vectoring, f-35, hover

I know fictional aircraft are different than real ones but there is an F38 on Black Ops 2 (F35 based plane in 2025)
http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/FA38

It appears in a mission like this

Could a F35 shoot while hovering?

Comment: I thought the B-variant didn't have a gun.

Comment: @jjack - It has a stealthy centerline gun pod with 220 rounds, more than the internal with 182 rounds. The pod isn't loaded when not needed. [Gun pod test footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUcln7StaEw) (first test, 120 round burst)

Comment: Please stop using the "fighter-jet" tag, it has been declared not-needed and it is being deleted.

Comment: @Federico Why ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it cannot, at least there is no reason for it to do so...

A) The stick while in "hover mode" does not control the pitch/roll of the aircraft, but the forward/lateral position of the aircraft. This means that the aircraft can only shoot forward in a level attitude, it can't pitch up/down to hit a target.

B) When in "hover" mode, the landing gear are deployed and the weapons doors are closed. The F-35 is not particularly maneuverable while hovering (it isn't meant for combat, only for landing/take-off), so you are extremely vulnerable while hovering anyway (you can't open the doors to fire missiles, you can't pitch up/down to fire guns). Combat is not a design scenario for hover mode on this aircraft.

C) The F-35 use a tremendous amount of fuel while hovering, to the tune of about 1000lbs *per minute*. It only holds about 13,000lbs of fuel. You aren't going to spend a lot of time hovering.

D) It only holds 220 rounds of ammunition.

As for why your game character is so dumb, you'll have to ask the game developers that question.

Comment: So there are no crazy maneuvers in flight like there were with the Harrier?

Comment: @jjack - The Harrier is even _less_ maneuverable in a hover, with ~4% excess thrust. The [F-35B was designed with ~10%](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-cfy-k_8ew) (LM was a bit overly conservative speccing the engine, which is understandable given the atrocious record of previous STOVL/VTOL fighter programs). During the initial competition, Boeing famously criticized LM's over-sized engine; LM in turn painted "Too Much Thrust" on one of its aircraft. If you're referring to VIFFing in the Harrier, all the pilot comments I've seen have basically said it was 'less than useful' in real combat.

Comment: Also, I think someone demoing the travel sim said something to the effect of  'selecting hover mode disables the weapons for safety.'

Comment: VIFFing is described here: https://jalopnik.com/5715656/the-eeriness-of-viffing-a-harrier I wonder, if they used it as an effective maneuver in combat, why pilots would describe it as less than useful. American experiences versus British, or a myth spread by someone. Or maybe just one British Pilots' maneuver against the experience of many others.

Comment: @jjack That is long discussed on the comments in the very link you provided. VIFF in air combat is probably a myth

Comment: @jean Where do they say so? In a video?